# Spring MVC Formatter and ManyToOne Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring mvc project. A Name class has a many to one relationship with a gender class. I have a Genderformatter to handle the select list needed for create and update name:

```
public class GenderFormatter implements Formatter<Gender> {

    @Autowired
    private GenderRepository genderRepository;

    public String print(Gender gender, Locale locale) {
        return gender.getId().toString();
    }


    public Gender parse(String id, Locale locale) throws ParseException {   
        Gender gender = this.genderRepository.findOne(Integer.valueOf(id));
        return gender;
    }
}
```

Here is relavent portion of the addupdatename.jsp

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="name" method="${method}"
          class="form-horizontal" id="add-name-form">
          ...
          <!-- Gender Select List -->
          <spring:bind path="gender">
            <c:set var="cssGroup"
              value="control-group ${status.error ? 'error' : '' }" />
            <div class="${cssGroup}">
              <label class="control-label">Gender</label>

              <div class="controls">
                <form:select path="gender">
                  <form:option value="${name.gender.id}" label="${name.gender.gender}" />
                  <form:options items="${genders}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="gender" />
                </form:select>
                <span class="help-inline">${status.errorMessage}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </spring:bind>
```

The NameController relevant GET and POST:

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/names/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String initCreationForm(ModelMap model) {
        Name name = new Name();
        model.addAttribute(name);
        model.put("genders", this.nameAdminService.findGenders());
        return "name/addupdatename";
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/names/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public String processCreationForm(@Valid Name name, BindingResult result,
          SessionStatus status) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
          return "name/addupdatename";
        } else {
          this.nameRepository.save(name);
          status.setComplete();
          return "redirect:/names/" + name.getId();
        }
      }
```

This all works fine. Now I'm adding CRUD functions for the Gender entity and running into problems. The GenderController and jsp objects follow the same pattern as the Name code. As long as the GenderFormatter is registered as a conversion service, the gender forms wont process add or updates to the data. I assume because on the gender add or update form post, the formatter is trying to convert the gender field to a gender object.

Is there a way to specify when or which fields a formatter should format?